# flex charts: datetimeaxis scrolling within disabled ranges

Tags: apache-flex, flex-charting

What is the best way to implement datetimeaxis scrolling within disabled date ranges  in Adobe Flex 3?

I use these classes for scrolling: http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/08/scrolling-and-zooming-chart-with-categoryaxis/

For chart scroll this library shifts minimum and maximum time values of DateTimeAxis.

While chart does not have disabledRanges set, everything is going well. When disabledRanges are set, the behavior of chart becomes weird.

Comment: Do you have a code example we could look at?